# DocuSign Connect Not Sending Out XML Messages

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to get DocuSign Connect to make HTTP Post request to my URL.

I have done some testing with POSTMAN app on google chrome and I am able to process the DocuSign XML Messages sent through this HTTP Post Request.

Attached is my setup.

I am unable to receive any messages from DocuSign (I have tried both sending and signing) and additionally I do not see any logs under Logs or Failures.
Is there any possible reason for this?

[image]

Updates: I was using a Self-Signed Certificate on my application and hence DocuSign was unable to post the XML message to my web service.
This has been resolved after installation of a DocuSign accepted certificate.

Comment: Thank you for the update and good work on figuring out the issue. Please *answer* your own question with the solution and then "check" it since it was the real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your account is configured properly for Connect and you do not see anything in the logs or failures here's some possible reasons:

- Security software or firewall on your side blocking/catching the message before it reaches your listener
- You are filtering for an envelope you do not have permission to.
- Your tests are invalid (i.e. you've configured for a signing event but the user is declining or taking some other action).

Also, I just realized you don't have **Require Acknowledgement** enabled in your Connect config- try turning that on to see if any failures start showing up.  Here's the description from the docs of this option:

`"Require Acknowledgment: Select this option to log posting failures. DocuSign waits 100 seconds for an acknowledgement before recording a failure. DocuSign logs a failure if the attempt to reach the external endpoint returns anything other than an HTTP 200. The acknowledgment failure messages are logged on the Failures page, which is accessed by clicking FAILURES on the Connect page. When this option is selected, DocuSign will automatically attempt to repost any failures. You can also manually repost from the Failures page."`

Comment: let me try turning on Require Acknowledgement. I am checking the events triggered from the admin account so I should have permission for those envelopes. Also, I have turned on Connect for all events so I'm assuming that is not the issue as well.

Comment: Got a log in error:<url> :: Error - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: I believe the issue is that my server is currently using a self-signed cert. Will update this to a DocuSign accepted certificate and update this question after. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, pretty positive that's your issue.  Cool let us know once you have a proper cert installed... thx

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have "Connect" enabled as one of the account's features. Do this using the admin tool (New DocuSign Experience) or Preferences in Classic.

Also, if you're trying out Connect on a production account, only some types of accounts include the Connect feature. Contact your Account Manager if it isn't enabled.

All Developer Sandbox accounts on the demo platform do include Connect.

All account types support webhook subscriptions at the envelope level using the eventNotification feature.

Comment: I am using a Demo Account on Classic and the "Connect" is enabled as one of the account's features. Hence, I am not sure why there are no messages sent out during my events.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using production account or sandbox account for docusign connect.. You must include the protocol HTTP or HTTPS in the web address for sandox account and you must include HTTPS:// in the web address for Production accounts because SSL is required in Production account. Docusign Connect sends the xml to the default ports of 443 for HTTPS: and 80 for HTTP. If you cannot use port 443 for Production contact DocuSign to review possible options. Check this [link](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/connect-technical-details.htm) for docusign connect technical information.. Hope you have handled the server side of it (i.e, the url which you have mentioned in the URL to publish) inorder to get the response from the docusign to the desired url when some event happens..

**For example:**

If you are using sandbox docusign account for Connect means, URL to publish as to be something like this http://domain.com/Home/DocuConnect (Hosted application port number as to be 80). For sandbox account,docusign connect are enabled defaultly for all the users.

If you are using production account for Connect means, URL to publish as to be something like this https://domain.com/Home/DocuConnect (Hosted application port number as to be 443). In some cases docusign connect are enabled based on the respective subscription plans. To check that go to features tab see for Docusign Connect and try to tick the checkbox and if it is not checked then you got to contact the Docusign Account Manager.